# Am I allowed to ask a question about explaining what some lines of a code does?

Tags: discussion

so I have recently started working with Arduino boards and C++, I was doing this project and with luck (meaning I tried random lines of code) I got what I wanted.

However, I don't want to learn this way so I want to ask the members in this site to explain how each line of code works (not the really basic ones). I don't know if I am allowed to do that or not? so please tell me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure you can. What we don't like are questions like:

> I got this code. Explain it to me.

In your case it's only parts of the code you need more understanding of. As long as you make it clear which blocks of code are confusing you and maybe how you think they may be working, we'd be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you are asking about a couple of lines of code. Don't post an entire sketch of hundreds of lines and expect a line-by-line explanation.